# Command not found: django-admin (using anaconda 3.2.4 and pyenv)

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm using Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11.3), pyenv and anaconda 3.2.4 and django 1.8.4
which I installed using the command

```
conda install django
```

I have tried both django-admin and django-admin.py, and neither have worked.

I have checked the $PATH which is

```
/Users/username/.pyenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Oracle/instantclient_11_2
```

When I look for django-admin.py in my files I can't see anything.

I have also tried the same for pyenv and Python 3.4.3, with no luck. (I installed django using pip).

My suspicion is pyenv is causing the confusion for the $PATH.

This is my first time using django.

Answer (score 0):

1) uninstall Django & Python

2) install Python via `brew install python`

3) install [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/), [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) with `sudo`

4) install [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/install/#installing-official-release) with `sudo`

Now you able to use `django-admin` . The key here is to install Python via brew